# GPA Calculator (division by zero) - Python

Tags: python, function, zero

This is my code for a simple GPA calculator. I am getting an error (see report) even though there is one course in the list as I follow the input and enter in the course. Maybe it has something to do with the placement of the call to the displayOutputTable function?

```
class Course(object):
    def __init__(self, courseName, letterGrade):
        self.courseName = courseName
        self.letterGrade = letterGrade


courseList = []

def acceptInput():
   courseList = []
   choice = input("Type ‘a’ to add new class or ‘e’ to end. ")
   if choice == 'a':
       courseName = input("Class Name? ")
       letterGrade = input("Grade? ")
   course = Course(courseName, letterGrade)
   courseList = courseList + [course]   
   print(courseList)
    # Create Course object using local data from user 
    # Add this new course object to courseList list 

def convertGradeToPoints(letterGrade):
  creditValue = 0  
  for i in courseList:
        if letterGrade == "A":
           creditValue = 4.0
        if letterGrade == "B":
           creditValue = 3.0
        if letterGrade == "C":
           creditValue = 2.0
        if letterGrade == "D":
           creditValue = 1.0
        if letterGrade == "F":
           creditValue = 0.0


        return creditValue

def calculateGPA():
    numbercourseList = len(courseList)
    totalpoints = 0
    for course in courseList:
        totalpoints  =  totalpoints + convertGradeToPoints(course.letterGrade)
    return totalpoints/numbercourseList

def displayOutputTable():
    print ("COURSE NAME \t LETTER GRADE \t POINTS")
    print("-------------------------")
    for course in courseList:
        print(course.courseName + "\t" + course.letterGrade + "\t" + convertGradeToPoints(course.letterGrade))   


    print("Total unweighted gpa" + "\t" + str(calculateGPA()))

acceptInput()
displayOutputTable()
```

here is the error report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/tester.py", line 56, in <module>
    displayOutputTable()
  File "C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/tester.py", line 53, in displayOutputTable
    print("Total unweighted gpa" + "\t" + str(calculateGPA()))
  File "C:/Users/Fred/Desktop/tester.py", line 44, in calculateGPA
    return totalpoints/numbercourseList
ZeroDivisionError: int division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
  Also, please look up "incremental programming".  You've written several blocks of code before testing any of them; there are several errors in the code, and you now face the task of finding and fixing *each* of them before you can get your program to appear to do anything useful.  Back up to just the input function, debug that, and don't add (or don't call) more code until you know that's working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

course[] is a global variable. You can only reassign a global variable in a local scope by first declaring it global to bind the global name to the local scope. Otherwise, when you do **courseList = []**, what's actually happening is a new variable named courseList is assigned a list in the local scope.

```
def acceptInput():
   global courseList
   courseList = []
   choice = input("Type ‘a’ to add new class or ‘e’ to end. ")
   if choice == 'a':
       courseName = input("Class Name? ")
       letterGrade = input("Grade? ")
   course = Course(courseName, letterGrade)
   courseList = courseList + [course]   
   print(courseList)
    # Create Course object using local data from user 
    # Add this new course object to courseList list
```

Alternatively, the way to do it by only mutating the LIST object without REASSIGNING it.

```
def acceptInput():
       courseList.clear()
       choice = input("Type ‘a’ to add new class or ‘e’ to end. ")
       if choice == 'a':
           courseName = input("Class Name? ")
           letterGrade = input("Grade? ")
       course = Course(courseName, letterGrade)
       courseList.append(course)   
       print(courseList)
        # Create Course object using local data from user 
        # Add this new course object to courseList list
```

Also, not sure why you want to clear your list of courses every time you accept input of a new course. You'll only ever have one course this way.

Edited for your comment:

> How do I make it so the console keeps asking me for input after I
>   submit one class

The answer to this is to use a looping construct, which is a fundamental basic construct of every imperative programming language out there. Perhaps you'd do well to consider learning from a basic python tutorial such as LearnPythonTheHardWay if you do not know this.

I'll also include a sigterm/sigint handler to handle ctrl+c without exception.

```
import signal
stop = False
def exit():
    global stop
    stop = True
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signum, frame: exit())
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda signum, frame: exit())
while not stop:
    acceptInput()
    displayOutputTable()
```

Comment: Fixed! Also how do I make it so the console keeps asking me for input after I submit one class. Right now I submit a class and the grade and it displays the ouput in a table and then that is it. It does not ask me for input again and therefore I have to run the function again to add another class. I just want it to keep asking until I press 'e' to end.